# What high paying low competition jobs/fields can a recent grad in electrical engineering go into?

Tags: job-search, career-development, career-switch

After two years of applying I haven't gotten any job offers despite having a high GPA.

What are some industries that guarantee high paying jobs that are easy to transition to with my background?

I don't want to waste any more time searching for jobs in the EE field. I have zero opportunities and zero potential in the EE field; there is no reason for me to keep looking for an entry level job in this field.

What other industries can an EE new grad find entry level work?

Comment: You might find better information by asking how to do a job search after two years of applying and not getting anything. Your school's job search office should have been the starting point two years ago. They might be able to help now.

Answer (score 3):

**No such role exists.**

If such a role *did* exist (a high-paying job that was easy to get, and no competition) then *everyone* in your field would start applying to it

.... meaning that either:

- this role would *acquire* a lot of competition

... or (if there was market capacity to employee almost all Electrical Engineers in this way)

- Electrical Engineering would become a guaranteed route to a guaranteed high-paying job.

Since Electrical Engineering is not *drastically* more complex or selective than any other high-end STEM specialism, that would lead to many many more student selecting Electrical Engineering as their study subject ... which would massively increase the pool of Electrical Engineers, which would saturate demand, which would lead to...

... this role acquiring lots of competition.